# If multiple jobs exist in the event loop for one process. What happens to the remaining jobs if the current job crashes the process?

Tags: node.js

In Node.js cluster mode, if multiple jobs exist in the event loop for one process, should the current job crash the process, what happens to the remaining job?

I'm assuming the remaining jobs in the event loop would go unfulfilled or return a server error. My question is, why is this an acceptable risk? Why would someone opt to use Node.js cluster mode in production then, rather than use something like PHP in production, where there is no risk of this, because PHP handles each request in its own process.

**Edit:**

Obviously this doesn't just apply to Node.js cluster mode. It can happen on a single instance, in which case obviously the end user would just get a server error. Cluster mode just happens to be my personal use case.

I'm looking for a way to pick back up a job in the queue job should a previous job cause the process to exit, before the subsequent job gets a change to be fulfilled. I am currently reading about how you can use a tool like RabbitMQ to handle your job queue outside of the node.js cluster, and each cluster instance just pulls jobs from the RabbitMQ queue. If anyone has any input on that, that would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why one would choose one environment over another involves thousands of different variables.  Nobody makes a choice on a single feature (or most don't).  If that's the single most important feature to you above all else, then you can pick an environment that delivers it for you or you can choose a different way to load balance among clustered processes. But, if a node.js process is crashing when just dispatching incoming requests, you've probably   got bigger problems.  No server is guaranteed to lose nothing when it crashes. That;s why we work really, really hard to keep things from crashing.

Comment: I might ask why in the world would one choose an environment that requires something as heavy-weight as a new process for every single incoming request.  That must scale horribly and perform horribly and not do well with lots of simultaneous requests..  Obviously, a choice like this is a huge tradeoff space depending upon lots and lots of things and priorities for a specific project.  In nearly all cases these days, you can work-around any platform's limitations if you care to put in the effort while exploiting its strengths.

Comment: Also, an incoming job can be in many places with a node.js cluster.  It can be in the OS queue (not handed off to node.js yet).  It can be in the node.js event queue waiting to be dispatched to a cluster or it can have already been dispatched and be in the clustered server's event queue or it can be in process on the clustered server. No matter where it is, if a server goes down, the client gets a TCP disconnect. The same is true for PHP.  If you'd rather have only one connection per process and the drawbacks of that, you can pick something that does that.  Many don't want those drawbacks.

Comment: That is some good input @jfriend00. It helps me look at things in another perspective. Thanks. FYI though I'm not saying one is better than the other. I'm just trying to get a better idea of the drawbacks and the reasons for choosing one over the other

Comment: I wouldn't put this issue anywhere on the radar for why you should choose one over the other unless you expect to be running risky code (perhaps out of your control) that crashes a lot and this issue is therefore more important in your deployment than all the other differences.  And, if that was the case, I'd probably isolate the risky code to its own process (even when using nodejs) to alleviate any pain from that crash.  You could have a worker pool waiting to process risky things.  For example, if you were running code submitted by a user, I might run that code in its own VM.

Answer (score 0):

> If multiple jobs exist in the event loop for one process. What happens to the remaining jobs if the current job crashes the process?

If a node.js process crashes, the same thing happens to it that happens to any other process.  All open sockets get automatically disconnected and the client will receive an immediate close on their socket (socket connection dropped essentially).

If you were using a Java server that was in the middle of handling 10 requests (perhaps in threads) and it crashed, the consequences would be the same. All 10 socket connections would get dropped.

If process isolation from one request to another is your #1 criteria for selecting a server environment, then I guess you wouldn't pick any environment that ever serves multiple requests from the same process.  But, you would give up a lot of get that.  One of the reasons for the node.js design is that is scales really, really well for a high number of concurrent connections that are all doing mostly I/O things (disk, networking, database stuff, etc...) which happens to be most web servers.  Whereas a design that fires up a new process for every incoming connection does not scale as well for a large number of concurrent connections because a process is a much more heavy-weight thing in the eyes of the operating system (memory usage, other system resource usage, task switching overhead, etc...) than the way node.js does things.

And, there are obviously hundreds of other considerations too when choosing a server environment.  So, you kind of have to look at the whole picture of what you're designing for and make the best set of tradeoffs.

In general, I wouldn't put this issue anywhere on the radar for why you should choose one over the other unless you expect to be running risky code (perhaps out of your control) that crashes a lot and this issue is therefore more important in your deployment than all the other differences. And, if that was the case, I'd probably isolate the risky code to its own process (even when using nodejs) to alleviate any pain from that crash. You could have a process pool waiting to process risky things. For example, if you were running code submitted by a user, I might run that code in its own isolated VM.

If you're just worried about your own code crashing a lot, then you probably have bigger problems and need more extensive unit testing, more robust error handling and need to take advantage of other tools just as a linter and other code analysis tools to find potential problem areas.  With proper design, implementation and error handling, you should be able to keep a single incoming request from harming anything other than itself.  That's certainly the philosophy that every server environment that serves multiple requests from the same process advises and the people/companies deploying those servers use.